# visualising a controllers procedural flow in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm finding it difficult to visualise exactly what the classes are doing in rails, and I don't fully understand how views are rendered.

Here is an example of code that I'm looking at (it was to create a simple user login).

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
        @user = User.new
  end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to(root_url, {notice: "Congratulations on signing up"})
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end

end
```

Please can you point out any inaccuracies in the way that I conceptualise this:

typing in the root url into the address bar:

1. send a get request to the web server to the root directory, and the server looks up roots, sees `root '/users#new'`.
2. server creates an instance of the UsersController class and calls the "new" method on that instance.
3. this method creates an instance of the User class and stores it as an instance variable of the UsersController instance. **Somehow**?? this results in the users/new.html.erb page being rendered, which is a form.
4. You full in the form and on submit you are posting back to the server (using post).
5. This automatically get directed to the users#create action and that bit of code is run using the variables stored in the params hash.
6. the instance of UsersController is discarded along with it's instance of the model, but the params hash remains until it is over-written?

Is this correct?

How is the view rendered?

and another slightly off topic question. are both post and get variables stored in the params hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should not think of everything as classes that instantiate into objects.

Let's think of a scenario where there is no web server, only an application server (Webrick or other).

In your scenario, the general case:

Writing a URL on your browser bar, will initiate a 'GET' request to the server.

Your server will the supply the caught request with all its data to an action in a controller, depending on a match against a set of possible alternatives called routes. Routes, you could imagine like regular expression with a few options attached to them.

Then, your data (`GET` in this case) is passed to the adequate controller action. There, depending on the logic, some objects (here it comes) may be instantiated from classes (like `@user` from `User`)

In the action, there will either be a directive telling rails what to render or a default directive will be followed (default directive: Render a view that has the same name as the action and is in the folder whose name matches the controller's name - all this is configurable).

When the view is rendered, ruby translates templates into HTML or other formats (depending on controller action requirements). The rendered output is sent to the browser through the same application server that received the request, creating thus a '`response`'.

Comment: thanks. one more question. a lot of the time you access the params hash - i.e. params[:id]. can these hashes be created by both get and post http requests, and does Ruby not discriminate between them?

Comment: From a general OO ruby perspective, it seems like thinking about everything in terms of objects is exactly what you want to do.  This particular problem may be easier to conceptualize without OO visualization, but it would be incorrect to not think of everything as having a beginning (instantiation).

Comment: @ZachSmith I believe every HTTP method is permitted a request body, both by protocol and by the [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: @ZachSmith, param hashes are produced by all types of requests. Actually, an HTTP request consists of various attributes. One is "method" (post, get, delete, patch, options etc). Then, a set of data. The hash in case of GET, is reachable through `params[:id]` (or other attribute). In case of a form, where there is the name of the form (`form_for @user` , for example), the params hash also contains the name of the form. So, the forms fields are in `params[:user][:id]` (etcetera)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your server log to see exactly what params are being passed before rails touches them and no the params hash does not contain the HTTP method used as that's already in the http headers, no need to put them in the params hash as well.

As for why `render new` shows the form in a filled out state.  That's because you set the variable in create and rendered the new template.  You're just rendering the new template and the new template doesn't care which action you've come from it just wants to see what variables you've got on you and fill in the template with matching Ivariables stuff.  You set the @variable in create and you called @variable in new.html.erb so it shows it.

Make sense or should I reword this?